# Can I set my user control datacontext in xaml via a dependency property bound to a property on the parent control in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user control with a dependency property called ViewModel. I want the value that this property is set to to be the data context for this control.

Here is an example of its usage;

```
<uc:MyCustomControl ViewModel="{Binding CustomControlViewModel}"/>
```

Here is the code-behind for the ViewModel dependency property for "MyCustomControl"

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ViewModel", typeof(CustomControlViewModel), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(CustomControlViewModel), PropertyChangedCallback));

    public CustomControlViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (CustomControlViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var control = (MyCustomControl) dependencyObject;
        if (control == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        control.DataContext = (CustomControlViewModel) dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
    }
```

This is the constructor for the "MyCustomControl";

```
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work, what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Why not set `<uc:MyCustomControl DataContext="{Binding CustomControlViewModel}"/>` from the start?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you don't need this property (because you can always directly access the DataContext property), your code looks ok, and it should work. As a note, the `null` check in the PropertyChangedCallback isn't necessary. The dependencyObject argument is never null.

Comment: @Clemens - Useful to know the dependencyObject is never null. I implemented the accepted answer that worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContext` itself is a `DependencyProperty`.  You can directly assign it with your viewmodel like this.

```
<uc:MyCustomControl DataContext="{Binding CustomControlViewModel}"/>
```